# In BLAST, how to get the HSP corresponding to each word?

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

In BLAST, I can only get a lot of sequences using its local and online services, but I cannot get the HSP corresponding to every word (seed) I want. According to the principle of BLAST, we know that the sequence will be divided into multiple words at the beginning, and then locate in the database according to these words, find multiple hits, and finally expand to the left and right sides. My question is how to get the HSP corresponding to a single word, instead of processing the completed result for me like online BLAST.Hope to get your suggestions, thank you very much.Attach the BLAST algorithm flow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skns8.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: Sorry, I am also looking for an answer, the code is a little bit impossible to start. I tried to find the corresponding module modification from the source code, but I found that the source code module was too complicated and there was no descriptive document. So it seems very difficult for me to change this step. Do you have any good suggestions, please leave a message.